# How to open firefox in linux by forcing the firefox not to ask for 'start new session, restore session' dialog?

Tags: linux, firefox

I am writing automated unit test plugins in java to open a firefox in a linux machine. I don't want the firefox to ask 'Start new session, restore sessions' dialog whenever my code is executing the 'firefox' command to start the firefox program. Is there any command line option in firefox command to tell the firefox program to not display this message? I am trying to google it but not finding any solution for this, Appreciate any help on this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know a command line argument, but you can adjust this behavior in firefox itself:

- type *about:config* in the URL field
- Filter for *browser.sessionstore.resume_from_crash* and set it to false

Comment: Thank for the response. I would like to rather have it with the command line option itself.